# How to access CSV config data set values in JSR223 PreProcessor

Tags: jmeter

I have set up a CSV DataSet Config in a Test plan which contains UserName and Password
UserName,Password
Anil,Test@123
Sunil,Test@123

How can I access these variables in JSR223 preprocessor ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance like:

   ```
    def username = vars.get('UserName')
    def password = vars.get('Password`)
   ```

   See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for JSR223 Test Elements
2. Pass the variables via Parameters section and access them as `args[0]` and `args[1]`

   [image]

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help